# Do chrome desktop apps use the proxy?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, proxy, desktop

I have the chrome browser on my linux laptop, and Chrome starting supporting web apps that can run on your desktop, instead of in the browser. So in my browser I configured a proxy, which is working properly.

Specifically, I would like to use JSTorrent, and am wondering if it Chrome's built-in proxy tool which I configured.

Answer (score 0):

this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchysharp/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm/related?hl=en) work for me , proxy can be switch by your setting.

Comment: Please exercise caution when recommending software. As written, your answer may be seen as spam. Your answer should include a description of the software and how it addresses the question. More information: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329)